# How can I stop com.apple.launched from attempting to start a service we uninstalled?

Tags: startup, launchd

My office used to use JungleDisk Workgroup service to exchange large files. We've moved on to a new solution and I uninstalled the client according to their instructions, but I noticed today in the Console that com.apple.launchd is trying to start JungleDisk every 10 seconds. It fails, but I can't help but think this is causing some performance issues.

Where/how do I remove a background service launch?

```
8/31/10 7:47:03 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.jungledisk.workgroupservice[4172]) Exited with exit code: 1 
8/31/10 7:47:03 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.jungledisk.workgroupservice) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds 
8/31/10 7:47:13 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.jungledisk.workgroupservice[4173]) posix_spawnp("/Applications/Jungle Disk Workgroup.app/Contents/Jungle Disk Workgroup/Jungle Disk Workgroup.app/Contents/MacOS/Jungle Disk Workgroup", ...): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a software, you can try [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/).

It allows you to manage (create, edit, delete) all the launchd items on your system.

Otherwise, if you want to go by hand, look inside the following folders :

- `/Library/LaunchAgents`
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons`
- `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Comment: `~/Library/LaunchDaemons` doesn't and isn't supposed to exist :-)

Answer (score 6):

The manual method (Lingon in Studer's question is a great GUI for this) is to unload the job from launchd:

Run `sudo launchctl stop com.jungledisk.workgroupservice` to tell `launchd` to stop running the job but it's important to note the job will just come back the next time you restart. You can then try and track down the file in `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `~/Library/LaunchAgents` - if you delete the file it won't load the next time you restart the computer. If you run `sudo launchctl unload /PATH/TO/com.jungledisk.workgroupservice.plist` this will unload the job and then you can delete the file since you don't require it anymore.